# Putting my company directory into Google Sites with pictures

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classic-sites

I'm using [this code](http://www.jacobjantuinstra.nl/domain) to pull the name and emails of my users into an intranet page on Google Sites. I was just wondering, is there some code that I can add to this so I can retrieve pictures? I would imagine it goes in below `flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i), 1, app.createLabel(user.getEmail()));` but I'm not sure what I can add there to retrieve their picture from their profile. I would also like to do the same for phone number.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
  var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();  
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable().setBorderWidth(1);

  for (var i=0, len=users.length; i<len; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i), 0, app.createLabel(user.getGivenName()
      + ' ' + user.getFamilyName()));
    flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i), 1, app.createLabel(user.getEmail()));
  }
  app.add(flexTable);
  return app;
}
```

Edit: I tried adding `flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i), 2, app.createLabel(user.getPhones()));` but that gives me an error in the code. I got this from the [API reference for scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/).

Comment: Perhaps you can post a solution? I will try as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible I'm afraid with the API used. The [API that's being used](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/) doesn't allow for more (basic) info to be retrieved.

There's however a new API released under Google Apps Script that can help you out:
[Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory)

This allows for much more tweaking !!

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried a few different attempts with the code above but as you said it doesn't allow for more info to be retrieved.

Comment: If I used your script for the spreadsheet version would I be able to manually enter the telephone numbers in the spreadsheet?          I get this error in my script with the spreadsheet: "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 9, file "Code")"